# Instantiate only an active child

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parent-child, instantiation

guys!
I've got a problem with instantiation. I am trying to instantiate a visible child object on the Raycast.  So far, I can instantiate only a parent object and cannot figure out how to instantiate only a visible child object.

[image]

Here is the code I am using now:

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray1, out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<SelectableTrunk>())
        {
                    GameObject STrunk = Instantiate(RandomSTrunk);
                    STrunk.transform.position = hit.point;
                    STrunk.transform.LookAt(hit.transform.position + hit.transform.forward, hit.normal);
        }
```

Comment: How are you assigning `RandomSTrunk`, maybe show the full script?

Comment: Your code shown doesn't provide enough context to answer the question. However, GetComponentInChildren by default ignores inactive objects.